# Асинхронное сохранение данных в Android средствами rx java2

Tags: android, асинхронность, rxjava

Добрый день. Для создания мультипоточности в Android использую RxJava2. Работаю с Single. Существует задача получения данных с сервера и сохранения данных в локальную БД. Получить данные и в том же потоке записать это не проблема, а вот чтобы после получения записать их в отдельном потоке используя принципы функционального программирования? Хотелось бы узнать каким образом Вы решаете такого рода задачи? Возможно Вы знете готовый оператор(который я не разглядел в документации) который позволит реализовать данное поведение.

Comment: смешались в кучу кони, люди... Как связана многопоточность и функциональное программирование? Если хотите писать данные в другом потоке (отдельный вопрос зачем?), то и создайте отдельный поток и пишите в нем

Comment: При использовании rx мы пишем в стиле функционального програмимирования. Сам же rx  позволяет нам облегчить жизнь в плане создания и обработки ассинхронных запросов. Описал ниже в комментарии к ответу @cmd что я хочу получить. Хочу найти оптимальное и красивое решение для дальнейшего его использования в своих проектах. Т.к. на данный момент делаю я следующим образом: "Получаю данные->Пишу в БД->Отдаю в UI", а хотелось бы получить "Получаю данные->Отдаю в UI и Пишу в БД(в отдельном потоке) при этом запуская на выолнение один обзервер, а не после получения данные запустить еще один для записи

Comment: rx и функциональное программирование - это две абсолютно разные вещи. Функциональное программирование подразумевает иммутабельность данных, что никоем боком не соблюдается в rx

Comment: Приведу отрывок из статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/306746/ ReactiveX или функциональное реактивное программирование предлагает альтернативный подход, который позволяет значительно сократить код приложения и создавать изящные понимаемые приложения для управления асинхронными задачами и событиями RxJava — реализация ReactiveX с открытым исходным кодом на Java.". Вот что я хотел сказать своим комментраим, просто не так удачно, как к примеру в отрыке данныой статьи

Comment: И суть даже не в том что мы с Вами сейчас будем разбрасывать терминологией, я просто хочу найти оптимальное решение(совет) для задачи. В принципе это все что я хотел получить из своего вопроса

Answer (score 1):

subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) позволяет записать данные в отдельном потоке, взятым из пула потоков .io.
observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.MainThread()) позволяет вернуть выполнение алгоритма в главный поток

Comment: Это я понимаю, но хотелось бы получить данные в UI и при этом параллельно записать их в БД, чтобы пользователя не заставлять ждать пока данные сначала запишуться, а потоv ему отобразяться, но реально ли это сделать  средствами операторов, а не запуска еще одного обзервера с колбеком. Что то вроде получили данные с сервера->отдали в UI поток и паралельно выполнить сохранение в БД. Противоречит ли это принципам функциоанального программирования? Хотелось бы решение, при котором максимально быстро вернуть данные пользователю и потом уже проводить какие либо еще манипуляции с ними

Comment: Такое поведение подразумевает двух субскрайберов с РАЗНЫМИ onNext/onCompleted. Соответственно либо publisher либо велосипеды

Comment: Спасибо, думал может что то универсальное есть либо кто то придумал интересный велосипед. Хотелось чтобы реализация оставалась на уровне репозитория и была скрыта от внешних глаз и при этом была асинхронна. Но видимо народ справляется так же как и я в основном.

Answer (score 0):

" хотелось бы получить данные в UI и при этом параллельно записать их в БД "

В таком случае, вы можете сделать так:

```
 someObservable 
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(object ->{ /*действие с ui*/ })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(object -> {/*Пишем в бд*/});
```